# Tamanho máximo de uma coluna MySQL

Tags: mysql

Boa tarde, pessoal! Estou com uma duvida...

Quero pegar o tamanho máximo de cada coluna de uma tabela, logo estou usando

```
SELECT MAX(LENGTH(nome_coluna_1)), MAX(LENGTH(nome_coluna_2)).... FROM nome_tabela;
```

O problema é que algumas coluna vêm com o valor correto do tamanho delas e outras vêm com o tamanho do registro (logo 0)... O que pode causar isso?

Obs.:É uma tabela com 120 colunas e todas são VARCHAR

Aceito novas sugestões no lugar de MAX(LENGTH()) haha

Comment: Talvez fazer uma consulta na tabela de schemas seja uma solução.

Comment: como faria essa consulta?

Answer (score 2):

É como disse o KaduAmaral, você pode fazer essa consulta:

```
SELECT character_maximum_length 
FROM   information_schema.columns 
WHERE  table_name = 'nome_tabela'
```

Comment: ok! Obrigado pela ajuda pessoal, deu certo!